# how to figure out font color given in subtitle (srt) in mpv

Tags: mpv, video-subtitles

For e.g. I have this sort of subtitle

```
1
00:01:55,201 --> 00:01:58,401
<font face="sans-serif" size="47"><font size="20"><b>It's absurd going to school
every day. The school's closed today.</b><font color="#ffffff"></font></font>
```

Now I'm unable to figure out the font color. Is there a way to get the color chart or give names or something that makes it clear what the color of the sentence is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#ffffff` = 255 red, 255 green, 255 blue, so that equals white.

Just look it up in `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There are also many open-source **color palettes** that show exactly what color correspond to a hexadecimal (for example **red** for **#FF0000**).

Here is [Coulr](https://github.com/Huluti/Coulr):

[image: Coulr]

But there are many others!
Arch Linux wiki has a dedicated entry in their List of Applications:

- [Color Pickers and Palettes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications#Color_pickers_and_palettes)